# how can i use XML file inside the fxml pane?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, fxml

i want to have a various xml template in my pane that is stored in my desktop similar to how we are adding images and and object inside the word document.is that possible?
can anyone help me with that? using javafx and fxml

Comment: You mean you want to drop elements in the pane and then save the result as xml?

Comment: nope i want xml files stored in my desktop inside the pane and that should be seen as template . (Similar to adding object inside the word document,like adding screenshots , another referrence document inside the word document) can you help me with this?

Comment: Actually that will be complicated.For adding images you have to use ImageView,References url button,For text a TextField.The xml file has to be synchronized with the template.You are asking for a lot of code here..

Comment: i am not asking for a code ....i am just asking for an idea is that possible?

Comment: @minnie Possible, but would not be feasible with such a broad context. You should try narrowing down the question to `dynamically load image into fxml` or something of that sort.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all ur valuable commands i made it work :-)